# National characters - save and resolve from cookies ASP.NET MVC + JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want save national characters to cookies in asp.net mvc, and then show them in javascript, but when I save this sentence: "Příliš žluťouličký kůň úpěl úděsné tóny." I got back this mass "PĹ™Ă­liĹˇ ĹľluĹĄouliÄŤkĂ˝ kĹŻĹ ĂşpÄ›l ĂşdÄ›snĂ© tĂłny.".
I'm using this construction for save data:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(string.Format("Flash.{0}", notification), message) { Path = "/" });
```

And this for reading:

```
function setFlashMessageFromCookie() {
    $.each(new Array('Success', 'Error', 'Warning', 'Info'), function (i, alert) {
        var cookie = $.cookie("Flash." + alert);

        if (cookie) {
            options.message = cookie;
            options.alert = alert;

            deleteFlashMessageCookie(alert);
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encode it in either base64 or urlencoding then decode it on the javascript side.

Answer (score 0):

With asp.net, try looking for System.Web.HttpUtility to encode and decode data.

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data); // encoding
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedData); // decoding
```

or try:

```
function setCookie(name,value)
{
    document.cookie = name + "="+ escape (value) + ";expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
}

function getCookie(Name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0){ 
        offset = document.cookie.indexOf(Name +"=");

        if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists 
          begin += Name.length+1; 
          end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset); 

          if (end == -1) 
              end = document.cookie.length;

          return unescape(document.cookie.substring(begin, end))
          } 
    }
}
```